# Gerar lista em outra aba com dados encontrados

Tags: microsoft-excel, excel-vba, fórmula

tudo bem?
Sou iniciante no excel e preciso da ajuda de vocês para criar uma planilha que gere uma lista em outra aba baseada no resultado encontrado.
Quando eu coloco uma data, preciso que copie a linha correspondente da data encontrada.
Ou seja, se eu colocar a data 05/01, preciso que copie a linha inteira de onde tiver o mesmo valor de data.
Exemplo: Dia 05/01: deve linha 1 e 2.
Poderiam ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, utilize o filtro avançado no Excel, nas versões mais recentes (Pelo menos 2016 acima), pode ser encontrado na guia Dados, no grupo "Classificar e Filtrar".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]